# Sweetalert 2 select dropdown and textarea at the same time

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am wondering if it possible to allow both select dropdown list and a input textarea within the same sweet alert.

For example: my select list have 4 options and the last option is others. I want when user choose others and it will display a text area for the user to enter. I am using similar to what sweetalert 2 give as shown below.

```
  swal({
  title: 'Select field validation',
 input: 'select',
 inputOptions: {
   'apples': 'Apples',
   'bananas': 'Bananas',
   'grapes': 'Grapes',
   'Others': 'Others'
 },
  inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
 showCancelButton: true,
 inputValidator: (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (value === 'oranges') {
      resolve()
    } else {
      resolve('You need to select oranges :)')
     }
  })
 }
  })

 if (fruit) {
 swal('You selected: ' + fruit)
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463649/sweetalert-prompt-with-two-input-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way (if you want to keep using the `input` and `inputValidator`) is that you can use the `html` property of swal to add an hidden text input (e.g. using `display: none`):

```
html: '<input type="text" id="fruit-text" class="swal2-input" style="display: none;">',
```

Then you can use the `onBeforeOpen` to subscribe to change event on the input, e.g.:

```
onBeforeOpen: (dom) => {
  swal.getInput().onchange = function (event) {
    if (event.target.value === "Others") {
      dom.querySelector('#fruit-text').style.display = 'initial'
    } else {
      dom.querySelector('#fruit-text').style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
```

},

An example of that can be found at https://south-carol.glitch.me/

Note that in this case, you should use the `preConfirm` to handle the status of the swal and return the value of the text input if needed (see source of the example at the url above)